# iOS: Buttons sizes relative or absolute?

Tags: ios, user-interface, screen, screen-density

i wonder what is the best practice for ui design for iOS regarding ui element sizing, especially buttons. In my example all buttons are based on images, no text.

I see two approaches

## Absolute Sizes

PRO:

- image based buttons do not need rescaling, avoids blurriness
- simple setup in interface designer

CON:

- buttons look smaller on bigger displays (ipad2 vs. iphone 4) relative to other ui elements

## Relative Sizes

PRO:

- buttons look better in whole ui appearance across all display resolutions and densities

CON:

- buttons may look blurry
- interface builder constraints will get a bit more complex

**Did i forgot something? Or did i get it wrong?**

For now i was designing the ui completely relative to the screen. So lets say a button had the width of 10% of the screen width and an aspect ratio of 1:1. When the ui was completely relative, everything seemed consistent across all devices. But my questions started in the scenario of @2x density buttons. The iphone 4 has a width (portrait mode) of 640 while the ipad2 has an width of 768. Should i create my @2x, 10% button image with a width of 77px or 68px? I would say 77 because downscaling is better than upscaling.

Well, this leads me to my question:

**What is the best practice to design the UI? How should we handle the image design for buttons?**

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is the text got stretched.
You can set the strech area by following this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

If you use gradient and it became blur when stretched, you need to draw the gradient using Core Graphics.

Comment: well, my buttons dont have text. they are just icons. And i maintain always the right aspect ration if i am working with relative sizes

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's **no ultimate approach** for laying out image buttons in iOS and it always depends on what you're trying to achieve.

In your case I would recommend the following approach:

1. Use layout constraints to position your buttons properly.
    Use only
   spacing constraints, **no width or height constraints**!
2. Set the images for your buttons (either in Interface Builder or in code).
    Make sure to provide each image asset in **all three resolutions @1x, @2x, @3x**.
3. If you have multiple buttons in a row give each of them a different horizontal compression resistance priority. This ensures that in case your buttons don't all fit on screen one (or more of them) will be scaled down to fit.

When assigning an image to a `UIButton`, that image will determine the button's [`intrinsicContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize). Thus, the button will automatically take the size of the image (if no other constraints with a higher priority are present) and it will only scale down if absolutely necessary (see number 3. above).

This approach is only possible if you still leave flexible spaces next to the buttons. If you intend to split the screen equally into three columns for example and each button should take the whole width of a column you have no other choice but do let the system scale down the images for devices with a smaller screen size. It always depends on whether you can allow the buttons to size themselves or if you need to force a width (or height) on the buttons from their superview.